# Divisibility function in SML

Tags: math, functional-programming, sml

I've been struggling with the basics of functional programming lately. I started writing small functions in SML, so far so good. Although, there is one problem I can not solve. It's on Project Euler (https://projecteuler.net/problem=5) and it simply asks for the smallest natural number that is divisible from all the numbers from 1 - n (where n is the argument of the function I'm trying to build).

Searching for the solution, I've found that through prime factorization, you analyze all the numbers from 1 to 10, and then keep the numbers where the highest power on a prime number occurs (after performing the prime factorization). Then you multiply them and you have your result (eg for n = 10, that number is 2520).

Can you help me on implementing this to an SML function?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: You might get better responses if you show what you've tried so far.  You might also want to look into the [least common multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple), which provides a simpler and more efficient way of solving this problem than using prime factorisation.

Comment: Thanks for your response! The thing is, I'm still trying to figure it out "on paper", I have no idea how would that be syntaxed in SML. I just started experimenting with it. The least common multiple that you suggested, works only between two integers, whereas I would like to compute the number for a given, finite set of integers. That's why I'm stuck actually.

Comment: The *definition* of least common multiple makes sense for any finite collection of integers.  Given an implementation `lcm` that works for a pair of integers, you can repeat to get an implementation that works for an arbitrary number of integers.  For example, the least common multiple of integers `a`, `b` and `c` can be computed as `lcm(lcm(a,b), c)`.

Comment: There is [some](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269920/should-questions-regarding-project-euler-be-allowed) [discussion](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/21383/project-euler-again) on how to deal with Problem Euler questions. But your main problem seems to be translating some algorithm into SML. If that is the case, I suggest you formulate the algorithm in some other language, or perhaps pseudocode, and point out which aspect of that you have trouble translating.

Answer (score 1):

Since coding is not a spectator sport, it wouldn't be helpful for me to give you a complete working program; you'd have no way to learn from it. Instead, I'll show you how to get started, and start breaking down the pieces a bit.

Now, Mark Dickinson is right in his comments above that your proposed approach is neither the simplest nor the most efficient; nonetheless, it's quite workable, and plenty efficient enough to solve the Project Euler problem. (I tried it; the resulting program completed instantly.) So, I'll go with it.

To start with, if we're going to be operating on the prime decompositions of positive integers (that is: the results of factorizing them), we need to figure out how we're going to represent these decompositions. This isn't difficult, but it's very helpful to lay out all the details explicitly, so that when we write the functions that use them, we know exactly what assumptions we can make, what requirements we need to satisfy, and so on. (I can't tell you how many times I've seen code-writing attempts where different parts of the program disagree about what the data should look like, because the exact easiest form for one function to work with was a bit different from the exact easiest form for a different function to work with, and it was all done in an *ad hoc* way without really planning.)

You seem to have in mind an approach where a prime decomposition is a product of *primes* to the power of *exponents*: for example, 12 = 2<sup>2</sup> × 3<sup>1</sup>. The simplest way to represent that in Standard ML is as a list of pairs: `[(2,2),(3,1)]`. But we should be a bit more precise than this; for example, we don't want 12 to sometimes be `[(2,2),(3,1)]` and sometimes `[(3,1),(2,2)]` and sometimes `[(3,1),(5,0),(2,2)]`. So, we can say something like "The prime decomposition of a positive integer is represented as a list of prime–exponent pairs, with the primes all being positive primes (2,3,5,7,…), the exponents all being positive integers (1,2,3,…), and the primes all being distinct and arranged in increasing order." This ensures a unique, easy-to-work-with representation. (N.B. `1` is represented by the empty list, `nil`.)

By the way, I should mention — when I tried this out, I found that everything was a little bit simpler if instead of storing exponents explicitly, I just repeated each prime the appropriate number of times, e.g. `[2,2,3]` for 12 = 2 × 2 × 3. (There was no single *big* complication with storing exponents explicitly, it just made a lot of little things a bit more finicky.) But the below breakdown is at a high level, and applies equally to either representation.

So, the overall algorithm is as follows:

- Generate a list of the integers from 1 to 10, or 1 to 20.

  - This part is optional; you can just write the list by hand, if you want, so as to jump into the meatier part faster. But since your goal is to learn the basics of functional programming, you might as well do this using `List.tabulate` [[documentation](http://sml-family.org/Basis/list.html#SIG:LIST.tabulate:VAL)].
- Use this to generate a list of the prime decompositions of these integers.

  - Specifically: you'll want to write a `factorize` or `decompose` function that takes a positive integer and returns its prime decomposition. You can then use `map`, a.k.a. `List.map` [[documentation](http://sml-family.org/Basis/list.html#SIG:LIST.map:VAL)], to apply this function to each element of your list of integers.
  - Note that this `decompose` function will need to keep track of the "next" prime as it's factoring the integer. In some languages, you would use a mutable local variable for this; but in Standard ML, the normal approach is to write a recursive helper function with a parameter for this purpose. Specifically, you can write a function `helper` such that, if *n* and *p* are positive integers, *p* ≥ 2, where *n* is not divisible by any prime less than *p*, then `helper n p` is the prime decomposition of *n*. Then you just write

    ```
    local
       fun helper n p = ...
    in
       fun decompose n = helper n 2
    end
    ```
- Use this to generate the prime decomposition of the least common multiple of these integers.

  - To start with, you'll probably want to write a `lcmTwoDecompositions` function that takes a pair of prime decompositions, and computes the least common multiple (still in prime-decomposition form). (Writing this pairwise function is much, much easier than trying to create a multi-way least-common-multiple function from scratch.)
  - Using `lcmTwoDecompositions`, you can then use `foldl` or `foldr`, a.k.a. `List.foldl` or `List.foldr` [[documentation](http://sml-family.org/Basis/list.html#SIG:LIST.foldl:VAL)], to create a function that takes a list of zero or more prime decompositions instead of just a pair. This makes use of the fact that the least common multiple of { *n*<sub>1</sub>, *n*<sub>2</sub>, …, *n*<sub>*N*</sub> } is lcm(*n*<sub>1</sub>, lcm(*n*<sub>2</sub>, lcm(…, lcm(*n*<sub>*N*</sub>, 1)…))). (This is a variant of what Mark Dickinson mentions above.)
- Use this to compute the least common multiple of these integers.

  - This just requires a `recompose` function that takes a prime decomposition and computes the corresponding integer.